# How can I combine specific data from two different excel files with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How can I transfer the links from `file2.xlsx` to the matching names in `file1.xlsx` using pandas?

**file1.xlsx**

```
0 Names Ratings Links
1 Joe   10
2 Jack  7
3 Jim   8
```

**file2.xlsx**

```
  Names Links
0 Jim   example.com/32145
1 Joe   example.com/35235
2 Jack  example.com/90234
```

**New file1.xlsx**

```
  Names Ratings Links
0 Joe   10      example.com/35235
1 Jack  7       example.com/90234
2 Jim   8       example.com/32145
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='Names')` or `df1.drop('Links', axis=1).merge(df2, on='Names')`

Comment: Do you know how to read the excel files into dataframes using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

If your first dataframe contains the `Links` column, you'll want to remove it:

```
df1.drop('Links', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Then,

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='Names')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  Names  Ratings              Links
0   Joe       10  example.com/35235
1  Jack        7  example.com/90234
2   Jim        8  example.com/32145
```